# How to prevent user from accessing the verification page after registration for verifying email in react-router-v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hey guys suppose my application has a verification page which is used to verify the user after registration, I want to prevent user from accessing this route manually and it should only be accessible by navigating the user from registration page . how can i check on verification page that user came here from registration page and if not then redirect it to registration page again.
Something like most web application does, for verifying users email. Do they store something in local-storage /sessions or pass something inside query parameters.

For example like on uber when i put my email it sends a verification code on my email with the link and navigates me to a verification page from registration page.
But am not able to come to this page manually so its preventing me.
If anyone can help , it will be great.

[image]
[image]

I have made the registration and login page , and setup all the routing but i have this doubt.

Comment: I solved this buy getting the information about if the registered user is verified. if the user is registered and verified, he is not able to access this page. you could also pass a state from your <Link> to the component <Verification> and check for that. <Link to={{ pathname: '/verification', state: { from: 'login' } }}> and: if (location.state?.from !== 'register') {…

Comment: @JohnDole can't we pass state with useNavigate() hook .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use an useEffect with some logic that if a query param is not met you can just push it to other page like homepage

something like this

```
 useEffect(()=>{

  if( some param not met ){

    Router.push("/")
  }

 })
```